# Phrase for describing a cable without a connector at the end

Tags: phrases, translation, terminology

I've been translating a truck scale description in a business offer letter, and the specification table there, listing the five parts comprising the prospective order, says on line five:

> Cable for connecting the load cell to the weighing terminal, **bare end**. Length: 30m.

In the Russian original, the phrase "открытый конец" (literally "open end") most likely means that the cable has no connector attached to it. It probably comes out of the load cell, and then is cut at this length, 30m. The Buyer can attach the necessary connector.

What would be a naturally-looking phrase for describing the same "bare end" in a similar English document?

([Also asked on Engineering SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10244/phrase-for-describing-a-cable-without-a-connector-at-the-end))

Comment: What's wrong with [bare end](https://www.google.com/search?q=bare+end+cable&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)?

Comment: @AlanCarmack - "bare end" seems okay, but one is never sure with technical terminology.

Comment: 'Raw Wire' also works (you can google it). As for as some industry standard/technical term, unless someone happens to know, then all we can do here--which seems reasonable, given that this is not a technical site--is give possible terms. Both 'bare end' and 'raw wire' are used.

Comment: I would use "bare end".

Comment: "No connector" would be informative.  :) http://www.ricelake.com/products/hardware/load-cell-hardware/cable/load-cell-and-indicator-connectors

Comment: As offered in the answer from @peter below, unterminated is the word that I would expect to see. Caveat - my background is in ICT, telecoms and agriculture. It's possible that a different word is used in other disciplines but I think all would understand unterminated.

Comment: Actually, your description in the question seems spot on.  Replace "bare end" with "without a connector at the end", and I do not think anyone would have trouble understanding.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the "cable" is used for load bearing, then you could use

> unfinished

[image: here]
<sub>(source: [chinahisea.com](http://www.chinahisea.com/upload/13-12-18/galvanized-steel-wire-rope.jpg))</sub>

However, if it is an electronic "cable", then the term

> unterminated

can be used.
[image: here]
<sub>(source: [gigalink-mce.net](http://www.gigalink-mce.net/images/robotic_cable.jpg))</sub>

Comment: And both can be sold as *bulk cable*.

Comment: Note: A "terminated" electrical cable could mean one with an impedance-matching resistor at the end, rather than one with a connector.

Answer (score 4):

**Pigtail** is also used frequently to mean an end of a cable that is un-connector-ized.
See [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Garmin-010-11074-00-Marine-NMEA-Network-Power-Cable-Pigtail-Only-/142008101565?hash=item211057aabd:g:EUgAAOSwMmBV3lR0&vxp=mtr) and [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Garmin-Mini-B-to-Serial-Pigtail-Data-Cable-Nuvi-Zumo-for-fleet-010-10813-00-/371592536269?hash=item5684a420cd:g:4QYAAOSwgApXAt~X).

Comment: Pigtail is a cable with one non-terminated end, but a connector on the other end. If that is the intent, then pigtail is better than "unterminated", "bulk" or "raw".

Comment: Exactly.  I got the impression from the description "Cable for connecting the load cell to the weighing terminal, bare end" that the other end is either hard-wired to, or has a connector that electrically attaches to, either the load cell or the terminal (description is ambiguous.)  If, alternatively, it is a cable used mechanically in the weighing process somehow, then 'bulk' would certainly be better.

Answer (score 1):

'Bare end' in this context is not unusual in the engineering community.

A quick search on the United Kingdom RS Components website http://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/?searchTerm=bare+end&sra=oss&r=t yielded several hits for this usage.

'Unterminated', 'bare cable', 'no connector fitted' and the like will also be widely understood.

A very puerile person might see innuendo in the term, but I would not worry about it.